# How to follow a list of links without id and name within CasperJS

Tags: casperjs

The below page code has a list of links that have no id and name to be used for click on it:

[image]

My casperjs code is problematic since it needs an id or name:

```
...        
    casper.then(function() {
        test.assertTextExists("User Data", "Login ok");
        test.clickLabel('Link_for_Data_1','a');
    });
...
```

Also by using the xpath with href seems not to work:

```
this.click(x('//*[@href="#cookpot-home/data-cookpot"]/a[text()="Link_for_Data_1"]'));
```

Some more page code, maybe it helps (the dark blue in the below picture is the part which has the link, see the first picture):

[image]

After some investigation I realized that it may need some more time to load the next page after the login to this page.
I added a wait timer for 10s but it still didn't helped!

```
...
    casper.then(function() {
        casper.wait(10000, function() {
            this.echo('should appear after 10s');
        });
    });

    casper.then(function() {
        console.log(this.getCurrentUrl());
        casper.waitForText('Link_for_Data_1', function() {
            this.echo('FOUND');
        });
        test.assertTextExists("Data page", "Login into Data");
...
```

The above code seems to work until it comes to the `waitForText` which never prints `'FOUND'`.
Also the `assertTextExists` fails, but according to the `getCurrentUrl` it is in the correct page (the page shows the text "Data page")!!!

So all the above seems to be a step to the right way but it still didn't answers my main question.